# How to shrink multi "external-graphic" inside block in XSL-FO

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I created a block in a block-container. And inside the block, there will be few number of external-graphic dynamically. I expected the width of the images should not exceed the block-container width.

```
        <fo:block-container width="90mm" display-align="center" text-align="center" margin-bottom="1mm">
            <fo:block line-height="0mm">
                <fo:external-graphic src="..."
                                     content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="scale-down-to-fit"
                                     display-align="center" text-align="center"/>
                <fo:external-graphic src="..."
                                     content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="scale-down-to-fit"
                                     display-align="center" text-align="center"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:block-container>
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your XSL-FO that has the problem?

Comment: I have updated with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have said to add `content-width="scale-down-to-fit"`, but you already have that.

You might try removing the `content-height` property, since the height of the `fo:block-container` is not fixed.

You could also try removing both `content-width` and `content-height` and adding `max-width="100%"` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#max-width).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the trick was to combine content-height="scale-to-fit" and max-width="100%". When i removed one of them (whatever which of them), the image exceeded.

```
<fo:external-graphic src="..." content-height="scale-to-fit" max-width="100%" />
```